# CursorAdapter bindView method gets updated cursor but not updating view in android 4.3 jellybean only

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

i am using the loader manager to get the local data from database and trying to show in the list view via cursor adapter

My listview contains the list of videos and have a functionality of renaming the video after renaming the video

Everything is working fine in all android version except android 4.3 jellybean list item is not updating with renamed text

my newview and bindview methods are as follows

```
public void bindView(View convertView, Context ctx, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    final int id = cursor.getInt(ID);
    final float length = (float) (cursor.getLong(LENGTH) / (1024f * 1024f));
    final String name = cursor.getString(NAME);
    final String path = cursor.getString(PATH);
    final long time = cursor.getLong(DOWNLOAD_TIME);

    holder.title.setText(name);
    holder.length.setText(String.format("%.2f", length) + " Mb");
    if (time != -1) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        String date = formatter.format(new Date(time));
        holder.date.setText(date);
    }
}



@Override
public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View itemLayout = mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.new_library_downloaded_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.length = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.length);
    holder.title = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.date = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.date);
    holder.preview = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.preview);
    holder.play = (ImageButton) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    holder.delete = (LinearLayout) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.delete);
    holder.share = (LinearLayout) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.share);
    itemLayout.setTag(holder);
    return itemLayout;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView length;
    TextView title;
    TextView date;
    ImageView preview;
    ImageButton play;
    LinearLayout delete;
    LinearLayout share;
}
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: great, and your problem really is ...?

Comment: @pskink  after renaming video the list item not updating with text

Comment: Where does your Cursor come from? and why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: i am using the loader manager so after renaming the video i am calling the restart loader method of loader manager and on loadfinished override method i swap cursor with updated cursor here loader manager calls everything on asyc thread

Comment: what ContentProvider are you using ? a custom one?

Comment: yes i have customized it

Comment: so post it, a query() and update() methods

Comment: as i have mentioned  in this holder.title.setText(name);  statement i got the name string correct means renamed string but it is not updating this holder.title view and that is specifically in 4.3 version

Comment: again why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: Following lines copied from developer site 

SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
This constructor was deprecated in API level 11. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) is not deprecated